# Pine Script Run Error "internal server pine compilation error" seen for NR4 Code

Tags: pine-script

I have written simple Narrow Range 4 Indicator Code in Pine Script of Trading View , The Source Code is error free.

Tried Debugging in many ways but couldn't figure out the error reason

```
//@version=3
study(title="Narrow Range 4", overlay=false)

currentHigh = security(tickerid, "1D", high[1])
currentLow = security(tickerid, "1D", low[1])
BarLength = currentHigh - currentLow

//Function for UP Count
NR_UP(TimeLineForToday,BarLen,currtHigh) =>
    MoveUpNR4 =0
    NR4PrevMin = lowest(BarLen[1],3)
    if BarLen < NR4PrevMin 
        MoveUpNR4 := iff( currtHigh > currtHigh[1],1,0)
   [MOVEUP] = MoveUpNR4*0.90


//Function for Down Count
NR_DOWN(TimeLineForToday_d,BarLen,currtLow) =>
    MoveDownNR4 = 0
    //NR4 
    NR4PrevMin = lowest(BarLen[1],3)
    if BarLen < NR4PrevMin 
        MoveDownNR4 := iff( currtLow < currtLow[1],1,0)
    [MOVEDOWN] = MoveDownNR4*0.8


 //Call NR4
 [MOVEUP] = NR_UP("1D",BarLength,currentHigh) 
 [MOVEDOWN] = NR_DOWN("1D",BarLength,currentLow)

 plot(series=MOVEUP,color = blue,linewidth=2)
 plot(series=MOVEDOWN,color = red ,linewidth=2)
```

This code should have produced simple 2 line plots on the tradingview.com chart.

Comment: Is this exactly the same code you are getting the error in the title? Because right now I am getting a different error: `line 14: Undeclared identifier MOVEUP`.

Comment: @BarisYakut  stackoverflow's making down ate (or added one extra) space

Comment: @Esha I applied the script and it works, without errors.

Comment: `[MOVEUP]` suppose that was an error. Make the last statement of a function like that: `MoveUpNR4*0.90` - the calculated value will be returned

Comment: @Michel_T. Yes, exactly. I just wanted to make sure that this code was the original. Usually "internal server pine compilation error"s are not code related.

Comment: @Michel_T Yes Code Compiles but I am getting this error at the Indicator Window, Just edited this code for the other small errors